# Sharing data between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm currently trying to make a create account fragment and a choose profile pic fragment.

#### Fragment A/create account:

This houses Edittextfields for name, password, E-mail address.
There is also an Image view which represents the profile pic.
This Image view has a button on the side, which I want to use to switch over to Fragment B.

[image: Design of the Fragment]

#### Fragment B/Choose Profile Pic:

Fragment is just an Image view and a couple of Image Buttons.

[image: Design of the Fragment]

#### My Problem

Let's say the user has typed in all information on Fragment A and now wants to choose a profile pic, how do I save all the data temporary which is entered in Fragment A. 
The second question is then, when the user clicks the Accept button on Fragment B, how do I sent the chosen Pic to Fragment A. So that I can switch over to Fragment A and restore the previously saved information and receive the drawable Image which the user has selected, to display it in the Image view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the new Android Architecture Components. Especially `ViewModel`.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing

There is a section on sharing data between fragments.

> It's very common that two or more fragments in an activity need to
>   communicate with each other. Imagine a common case of master-detail
>   fragments, where you have a fragment in which the user selects an item
>   from a list and another fragment that displays the contents of the
>   selected item. This case is never trivial as both fragments need to
>   define some interface description, and the owner activity must bind
>   the two together. In addition, both fragments must handle the scenario
>   where the other fragment is not yet created or visible.
>
> This common pain point can be addressed by using ViewModel objects.
>   These fragments can share a ViewModel using their activity scope to
>   handle this communication, as illustrated by the following sample
>   code:

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

    public void select(Item item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}

public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(this, { item ->
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks works like a chram. For other people that might use this, be aware, that you have to use Fragment and FragmentActivity from `android.support.v4.app.` instead of the "normal" Fragment and Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Making Activity as an intermediate can enable your fragment communication.
Refer [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for "fragment-activity-fragment" communication. If you want to persist the data refer SharedPreference of android.

Answer (score -2):

Why you want to create 2 Fragments ?

You can achieve same thing with different views. Let's say you can create one Linear/Relative(Layout Group) Layout with all the controls of 1st Fragment and create another layout(Layout Group) with 2nd Fragment controls. And then using animation show and hide layouts so you can have both the things in same fragment or activity and user won't even notice that thing.

This way you don't have to save data temporary and you will have to implement all the things in single file.